# How to get the screen resolution without Windows Forms reference?

Tags: c#, .net-core, screen-resolution

I need to get the resolution of the desktop my test runs on. Previously I was grabbing the resolution like this:

```
Screen screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
int screenWidth = screen.Bounds.Width;
int screenHeight = screen.Bounds.Height;
```

Unfortunately, using `System.Windows.Forms` isn't possible anymore. My project is .NET Core, so preferably I need a NuGet package for this.

If anyone's got any suggestions I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Great, thanks I'll look into it now and let you know if I'm successful. No I'm not targeting Windows in particular - trying to grab the resolution to change it back to the original resolution after running a test that changes it.

Comment: I just noticed that's for C++. That solution won't work for my C# issue.

Comment: If you'd be able to write the code in C# to demonstrate what you mean, would be great.

Comment: Yeah, only targeted OS to run this code on would be Windows. Apologies I mid-understood what you were asking previously.

Comment: @Mike .NET Core doesn't support desktop UI applications yet. That's coming in .NET Core 3.0. What do you want the screen size anyway when the only UI you can access is either the console or a web page? Shouldn't you be looking for ways to access the console?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos reason for that is because we're performing automated UI tests that change resolutions mid-test. I wanted to grab the original so that I can change the resolution back towards the end of the test.

Comment: @Mike how do those tests change resolution if you can't access the UI in .NET Core? OTOH if you want this for a testing tool you can add the .NET 3.0 SDK to your machine.

Comment: Using Windows API.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want to use `System.Windows.Forms` (or cannot), you can get the screen resolution by using a Windows API function [`EnumDisplaySettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsw).

To call the WinAPI function, you can use the P/Invoke feature that is also available on .NET Core. Please note that this will only work on a Windows system, because there's no WinAPI on non-Windows targets.

The function declaration looks as follows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE devMode);
```

You also need the WinAPI `DEVMODE` struct definition:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct DEVMODE
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
  public string dmDeviceName;
  public short dmSpecVersion;
  public short dmDriverVersion;
  public short dmSize;
  public short dmDriverExtra;
  public int dmFields;
  public int dmPositionX;
  public int dmPositionY;
  public int dmDisplayOrientation;
  public int dmDisplayFixedOutput;
  public short dmColor;
  public short dmDuplex;
  public short dmYResolution;
  public short dmTTOption;
  public short dmCollate;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
  public string dmFormName;
  public short dmLogPixels;
  public int dmBitsPerPel;
  public int dmPelsWidth;
  public int dmPelsHeight;
  public int dmDisplayFlags;
  public int dmDisplayFrequency;
  public int dmICMMethod;
  public int dmICMIntent;
  public int dmMediaType;
  public int dmDitherType;
  public int dmReserved1;
  public int dmReserved2;
  public int dmPanningWidth;
  public int dmPanningHeight;
}
```

Actually, you don't need most of this structure's fields. The interesting ones are `dmPelsWidth` and `dmPelsHeight`.

Call the function like this:

```
const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;

DEVMODE devMode = default;
devMode.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(devMode);
EnumDisplaySettings(null, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref devMode);
```

Now you can check the screen resolution in the `dmPelsWidth` and `dmPelsHeight` fields of the `devMode` struct.

Since we specify `null` as first argument, the function describes the current display device on the computer on which the calling thread is running.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! I will have a look very soon so hopefully I can implement this into my project.

Comment: This is brilliant! Works exactly how I'd like it to. I had most of this code already as I'm using this to change resolution... Only part I'm struggling to understand is the function. What is it doing exactly to contribute to the width and height values? Thanks!

Comment: This is a WinAPI function. It calls the operating system internal routines which forward the call to the video driver. The video driver fills the information of the structure `DEVMODE` you provide. If this answer is helpful, you can upvote and accept it.