# Type cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure

Tags: c#, winapi, struct, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to change the resolution in a core project.

```
var devmode = default(Devmode);
devmode.DmDeviceName = new string(new char[32]);
devmode.DmFormName = new string(new char[32]);
devmode.Dmsize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(devmode);
```

On the 3rd line of the above code, it fails and produces a "cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed" error.

Can anyone provide some insight into how I should go about fixing this? The weird thing is it was working fine before I pulled some other code that shouldn't have effected this code.

Struct:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Devmode
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string DmFormName;
    public string DmDeviceName;

    public short Dmsize;

    public int DmPelsWidth;
    public int DmPelsHeight;

    private readonly short dmlogPixels;
    private readonly short dmbitsPerPel;
    private readonly int dmdisplayFlags;
    private readonly int dmdisplayFrequency;
    private readonly int dmiCMMethod;
    private readonly int dmiCMIntent;
    private readonly int dmmediaType;
    private readonly int dmditherType;
    private readonly int dmreserved1;
    private readonly int dmreserved2;
    private readonly int dmpanningWidth;
    private readonly int dmpanningHeight;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    private readonly short dmspecVersion;
    private readonly short dmdriverVersion;
    private readonly short dmdriverExtra;
    private readonly int dmfields;
    private readonly int dmpositionX;
    private readonly int dmpositionY;
    private readonly int dmdisplayOrientation;
    private readonly int dmdisplayFixedOutput;
    private readonly short dmcolor;
    private readonly short dmduplex;
    private readonly short dmyResolution;
    private readonly short dmtTOption;
    private readonly short dmcollate;
}
```

EDIT: I've now changed the code to this:

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Devmode
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]

        private readonly string dmdeviceName;

        private readonly short dmspecVersion;
        private readonly short dmdriverVersion;

        public short Dmsize;

        private readonly short dmdriverExtra;
        private readonly int dmfields;
        private readonly int dmpositionX;
        private readonly int dmpositionY;
        private readonly int dmdisplayOrientation;
        private readonly int dmdisplayFixedOutput;
        private readonly short dmcolor;
        private readonly short dmduplex;
        private readonly short dmyResolution;
        private readonly short dmtTOption;
        private readonly short dmcollate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
        private readonly string dmformName;
        private readonly short dmlogPixels;
        private readonly short dmbitsPerPel;

        public int dmpelsWidth;
        public int dmpelsHeight;

        private readonly int dmdisplayFlags;
        private readonly int dmdisplayFrequency;
        private readonly int dmiCMMethod;
        private readonly int dmiCMIntent;
        private readonly int dmmediaType;
        private readonly int dmditherType;
        private readonly int dmreserved1;
        private readonly int dmreserved2;
        private readonly int dmpanningWidth;
        private readonly int dmpanningHeight;
    }
```

However I am getting an error for dmpelsWidth, dmpelsHeight and Dmsize. 'Public' members must come before 'private' members...

Any ideas?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve]

Comment: @dymanoid I've added the struct code, feel free to take a look. :)

Comment: @dymanoid I've updated the code I'm using along with the errors I'm now getting.

Comment: These are not compiler errors. These errors originate form a static code analysis tool or from a tool like StyleCop. Make sure you exclude the struct from being processed by those tools.

Comment: Thank you very much @dymanoid, you've taught me quite a lot over the past couple of days. Used a SuppressMessage statement which solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DmDeviceName` field is missing the `MarshalAs` attribute.

It should look like:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
public string DmFormName;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
public string DmDeviceName;
```

By the way, this code is pointless:

```
devmode.DmDeviceName = new string(new char[32]);
devmode.DmFormName = new string(new char[32]);
```

Just remove those lines. The values will be filled by the called WinAPI function (when possible).

And the biggest problem is: **your struct definition is invalid**! The field order is **important**! You are not allowed to *reorder the fields*. Please use the struct definition as I [posted in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836927/2846483).

Comment: Oh ok that's what I messed up then! Thanks for your input, very much appreciated. I had to re-order the fields because of errors that private should be before protected fields etc.

Comment: Ok so I've changed it back to the previous layout as you instructed... However now I've got the problem of, "Public fields must come before Private". Keep in mind I need DmPelsWidth, DmPelsHeight and Dmsize to be public/protected.

Comment: No you don't need those fields to be public or protected. You can expose them with a property. However, for a structure like this you may as well make all field public.

Comment: I make them private & read only because Bamboo requires that to build it successfully. This is where I'm having an issue...

Comment: This `struct` is for P/Invoke. You should exclude this struct from static code analysis or add a diagnostic rule suppression to avoid build errors.